# Parsing and printing JSON result after GET request using Python

Tags: python, json, get

I try to make a clear result of a json result after a GET request on Python :

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get("https://smspva.com/api/rent.php?method=getcountries")

parsed = json.loads(r.text)

print(parsed)
```

I got result like that :

```
{'status': 1, 'data': [{'name': 'Russian Federation', 'code': 'RU'}, {'name': 'Ukraine', 'code': 'UA'}, {'name': 'Germany', 'code': 'DE'}, {'name': 'Czech Republic', 'code': 'CZ'}, {'name': 'United Kingdom', 'code': 'UK'}, {'name': 'Sweden', 'code': 'SE'}, {'name': 'Spain', 'code': 'ES'}, {'name': 'Portugal', 'code': 'PT'}, {'name': 'Netherlands', 'code': 'NL'}, {'name': 'Lithuania ', 'code': 'LT'}, {'name': 'Latvia', 'code': 'LV'}, {'name': 'Ireland', 'code': 'IE'}, {'name': 'Estonia', 'code': 'EE'}, {'name': 'United States', 'code': 'US'}]}
```

How can i get something like :

Name : Russian Federation
Code : RU

Name : Ukraine
Code : Ua

etc etc

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Response.json()`. Then iterate over `data` key:

```
import requests

resp = requests.get("https://smspva.com/api/rent.php?method=getcountries")
data = resp.json()
for country in data.get('data', []):
    print(f"Name:{country.get('name')} Code:{country.get('code')}")
```

Comment: Amazing thanks you !

Comment: I try to adapt your solution but it doesnt work :(